# Flutter on page focus event?

Tags: flutter, dart, state

initState() will always call on the initialization of a page, and thats great.

But, what if I have 2 screens

Screen 1 navigates to screen 2. Now, when you press back on page 2 (pop) is there an event on page 1 that knows we are back again?

In other words, can Screen 1 fire an event on the back press of page 2?

This is useful to set the state, of say, a global variable that changed on screen 2, so screen 1 can update accordingly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can `await` `Navigator.push()` which will resolve when route is popped.

In Screen1 :

```dart
await Navigator.push(context, Screen2);
// Do something when Screen2 is popped
```

You can also pass data from `Screen2` to `Screen1` with `pop()` :

In Screen2 :

```dart
Navigator.pop(context, data);
```

In Screen1 :

```dart
final dataFromScreen2 = await Navigator.push(context, Screen2);
```

Comment: This really works well. Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can make by 3 different ways depending on what you want exactly.

1. `popEvents` (my favourite): You can use `WillPopScope` widget on page 2 to prevent back buttons to exit the page.

```
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: (){
            return Future.value(a==b); //Replace by your conditionals here. false means you're block back action for this page
          },
          child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: Center(
    
          ),)
        );
      }
```

2. Listen only for page2 (only if you want to check execute code on Page1)

- page2: this is needed only if you want to execute your code on Page1 depending on the result of page2.

```
    Navigator.pop(data);//this is the data you want to send back to Page1
    //if user presses back button, it's same like Navigator.pop(null)
```

- Page1:
  use the sent by Page2

```
    final result = await Navivigator.push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx)=>Page2()));

    if (result != null) {
        //do something
    }
```

3. You want to listen for the whole app lifecycle events. By this way, You can check anytime when user comes back to Page1  if tasks has been correctly executed. or not

- Init binding

  ```
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  ```
- In page One add `WidgetsBindingObserver` mixin to your page

  ```
    class Page1State extends State<Page1> with WidgetsBindingObserver
  ```
- Override `didChangeAppLicycleState` method: this will pass the current state of your page or the whole app state event like going background...

```
    @override 
    void didChangeAppLicycleState(AppLifecycleState state){
    if(state = AppLifecycleState.paused){
    //do whatever you want here
       }
    }
```

Comment: Unless I am missing something, didChangeAppLicycleState() does not get called when returning to a view. Only when the lifecycle changes such as bringing the app/view back into focus from the background.

Comment: Yes it's true. But like I said in section 3. This is for the whole app lifecycle. Like you when you opened an intent(android) and you are back to the and want to perform some tasks...